# Polymer 3 with Visual Studio

Tags: polymer-3.x

Does anyone know how to get Polymer 3 running with Visual Studio?

I have completed a demo using the polyserve development server.  However, I cannot get the same code to work in Visual Studio.  I would not think it would depend on the hosting environment.

I created a polymer element using these instructions:
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/start/first-element/intro

It works as expected.  When I move the code to visual studio I get:

> Failed to resolve module specifier
>   '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js'

I have noticed that when I run  polyserve I get 64 requests for this page.  When I do it in Visual Studio I get 3 - my html, webcomponents-loader.js, and demo-element.js

Comment: you have to use polymer serve for polymer development does not matter which editor you use.

Answer (score 0):

**It does not matter which editor you are using**. I use VS Code only for polymer-3.x.

After you have installed polymer in your local, you can create your element using [polymer CLI](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/polymer-cli-commands).

- create a directory where you want to start your project and `cd` inside the directory
- open the terminal at this location and type the following polymer cli commands
- `polymer init` -> select `polymer-3-element`, this creates your hello world element
- `polymer serve` starts server. you can view your element `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I have done that.  It works.  Can it not be hosted with IIS?